# Detect trigonomitric functions from function result

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

Is it possible mathematically to determine if a function a trigonometric function like :

`5*cos(4x+2)` or `sin(1/2x)` ...

By only seeing the result ?

I am working on code which evaluate JavaScript function `function f(x){ return Math.sin(x*2); }` to see if it is trigonometric based on the result .

Not a valid function because it always return 1 not a harmonic values:
`function f(x){ return Math.pow(Math.sin(x),2) + Math.pow(Math.cos(x),2); }`

This function is valid `function f(x){ return 1/4 * Math.cos(x*5) }`

This on is not valid `function f(x){ return x*Math.sin(x); }` And So On ...

Comment: Define the scope. What is/isn't valid?

Comment: Just wondering if this question should be on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I thought about putting it on Math Exchange but I am doing it on JavaScript and since Math and Programming are strongly related I decided to ask it here

Answer (score 0):

First,

> 1=cos(0·x)=cos(x-x)=cos²(x)+sin²(x)

is valid under your constraints.

---

Second, even under the assumption that the function is periodic (with further small restrictions), you can approximate it very closely using trigonometric polynomials.

And considering that a large class of  functions can be represented via Fourier integrals, which can be approximated by finite sums of sinusoids with incommensurable frequencies, it makes your task even more impossible.

---

However, you can empirically and heuristically interpolate of approximate a part of the sampling set via some trigonometric polynomial and then test via the remaining samples a la machine learning. Variations are given via the fundamental, i.e., minimal and the maximal frequency, which determines the number of terms. You can also remove terms with too small coefficients to reduce the complexity of the expression.